# How to update a single row in C# mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

My problem is that

1. It updates all the data with the same id. Because I have a multiple data with the same id. [see the picture below].
2. I want to update only the row with near expiration (30 days). I don't want to do anything with those items that are already expired.

Here is my code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewPOS.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"UPDATE inventory2 SET quantity = @quantity WHERE itemid = @itemid ORDER BY expiry", sqlconnection);
            //codehere
        }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydmOh.png)

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

```
       for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewPOS.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM inventory2 WHERE itemid = @itemid ORDER BY expiry", sqlconnection);
            //codehere

            cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"UPDATE inventory2 SET quantity = @quantity WHERE itemid = @itemid AND CURDATE() < expiry ORDER BY expiry", sqlconnection);

            //codehere
        }
```

Comment: What does "near expiration" mean to you?

Comment: I set a expiry like 2017 and 2018 and I only want to update the data were the expiry is near the current date like 2017

Comment: you need to add more information to your problem

Comment: `ORDER BY` in `UPDATE` doesn't do what you think it does.  If you want to only update those rows "near expiration" then you have to include that criteria in the `WHERE` clause.  Tip to make sure you know what you're updating/deleting: try practicing getting only the rows you want updated by running a `SELECT` with the proper criteria before doing `UPDATE`.

Comment: I just added some info.

Comment: @Philip the problem isn't your data it's the word "near" what does this means, Expires in 1 minute, 1 hour, 1 day, 1 week, 1 month, 1 year, 1 decade, 1 Century?

Comment: Oh I see. its 30 days

Comment: in that case you need to check if expiry less than current date + 30 days which is the DATE_ADD function http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check the expiration in the SQL
 ie

```
WHERE itemid = @itemid and CURDATE() < expiry
```

the exact nature of your where depends on how you define "Near"

```
WHERE itemid = @itemid and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) < expiry
```

This would be within 30days of expiry

once you have your "Near" date you could then combine with a select max

```
AND expiry = (SELECT MAX(expiry) FROM inventory2 WHERE itemid = @itemid)
```

so get just the largest

EDIT: the information you added says you want to edit records not expired this is the exact opposite of what your original question seemed to imply as such you need to do

```
expiry BETWEEN CURDATE() and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

this will get everything that will expiry in the next 30days but hasn't already expired

Comment: Thanks I'll try this one too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something closer to:

```
UPDATE inventory2 
    SET [quantity] = @quantity 
    where [itemid] = @itemid 
        AND [expiry] between CURDATE() and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Your command code would change to:

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"UPDATE inventory2 SET quantity = @quantity WHERE itemid = @itemid AND [expiry] between CURDATE() and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY", sqlconnection);
```

This will update all rows from inventory2 where the itemId matches and the expiry date is less than the current date plus thirty days.

EDIT to reflect updated requirements from comments: Item not expired, item expires within 30 days

Comment: The problem with vague requirements. What would happen if the nearest expiration is in 20 years?

Comment: @apokryfos Then the query updates that item.  What other functionality would we want at the point? The next item to expire gets updated no matter how close or far it is from the current date.  I would be more concerned about updating an item with a past expiration date.  I would assume that would be bad.

Comment: @apokryfos with out a definition of near this answer is as good as any other

Comment: @JaredStroeb you missed part of the update it now says "I don't want to do anything with those items that are already expired."

Comment: @MikeT Thanks I have included that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you will have a unique id for the table. Why not do a select query first to get the unique id and then update that row with the unique id reference. In fact you should be able to merge both in one query too. Bottomline is to use the unique id and return only 1 row in the select query after ordering it in the manner which puts your near expiration at the top.